# Is Keycloak/Oauth2 usage possible in Spring Security 6.0 without writing an Oauth2 provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

Spring Boot 3.2.2 and Security 6.2.1 seem to require me to code an OAuth2Provider, where in Boot 2.5.6 (Security 5.5.3) I achieved OAuth2 functionality thru configuration.

My Spring Boot 2.5.6 app serves Angular client code and a REST API and is secured with Oauth2 using a separate Keycloak 23 installation. Everything works fine. Keycloak is configured in application.yml. Spring apparently reads the oidc endpoints and presents any non-authenticated request to the OIDC authorization endpoint on Keycloak with the correct parameters. The client obtains a token which it uses against the server. The REST endpoints are usable. Just to be clear, here is part of the Maven pom from this working app

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>   
</parent>
...
<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>     
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>                   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>          
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>  
...
```

Nowhere in the app are the authorization-grant-type or the authorization-endpoint configured. The well-known oidc config endpoint is configged. I have no login/logout code, and no user service with profile details, on the server. I don't need roles. I interact with Keycloak in the client via the angular-oauth2-oidc library from M Steyer.

I cannot figure out the equivalent of this basic, self-configuring setup with the current Spring Boot (3.2.2) and the dependencies that Maven pulls in. (Security 6.2.1, etc). The examples I see are for the multiple client use case, using the CommonOauth2Providers, e.g., GOOGLE, FACEBOOK, OKTA. The clients all have client-secret. I can set confidential access and get a secret for my client in Keycloak; is it necessary? Do I need to configure login/out, user service, a client registry, registry manager? Do I need to configure the info that the working app found on Keycloak thru the well-known oidc config endpoint?

I'm surely not the first person to encounter this problem, but I cannot offhand find an existing discussion of the basic case. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, Keycloak/Oauth2 usage is possible in Spring Security 6.0 without writing an Oauth2 provider.

If you are using an OAuth2 client library in Angular (like `angular-oauth2-oidc` is), then:

- Authorization-code flow configuration is to be done in Angular app, not Spring one
- you can't use a "confidential" client: applications running on end-user devices can't keep a secret and have to be configured as "public" clients
- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` in your boot application is mostly useless (the OAuth2 client is the Angular app)
- requests from Angular to the Spring REST API are authorized with access tokens (the Spring app should be configured as a resource server, most probably with a JWT decoder in the case of Keycloak as authorization server)
- you are applying something that [is now considered a worst practice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) (if you don't feel like reading the all post, skip directly to the **Final Recommendation**)

You should probably remove `angular-oauth2-oidc` from your Angular dependencies and insert an OAuth2 BFF between your Angular app and your REST API. It will bridge between session + CSRF security (between the end-user browser and your backend) and token security (inside your backend).

For more details about Spring OAuth2 config, see [Spring Security manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/) or [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2).

Be careful that spring-cloud-gateway, which is a natural choice for implementing an OAuth2 BFF (with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `oauth2Login()` and the `TokenRelay` filter), is a *reactive* application, and that security beans to expose are different than those required for *servlets*.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for your comments. Here is spring-cloud-gateway.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Comment: See also Jerome's tutorials as linked

https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2